# ReactiveCocoa: View doesn't update when ViewModel property changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I cannot understand, why my `View` doesn't update after `ViewModel` changes.

I have binded my button properties in `View`:

```
- (void)bindViewModel
{
    // ViewModel -> View
    RAC(self.nextButton, backgroundColor)   = RACObserve(self.viewModel, nextButtonColor);
    RAC(self.nextButton, enabled)           = RACObserve(self.viewModel, nextButtonEnabled);
}
```

This is my `ViewModel`:

```
@implementation REBaseAuthViewModel


- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if ( self ) {

        RACSignal *inputValidSignal = [RACObserve(self, textFieldText)
                                       map:^id(NSString *text) {

                                           BOOL b = [self validateInput:text];
                                           NSLog(@"Input is valid: %d", b);
                                           return @(b);

                                       }];
        RACSignal *inProressSignal = RACObserve(self, inProress);


        RAC(self, nextButtonEnabled) = [[inputValidSignal
                                         combineLatestWith:[inProressSignal not]]
                                        and];
    }

    return self;
}


- (BOOL)validateInput:(NSString *)text
{
    return text.length > 0;
}


- (void)setNextButtonEnabled:(BOOL)nextButtonEnabled
{
    _nextButtonEnabled = nextButtonEnabled;

    NSLog(@"nextButtonEnabled: %d", nextButtonEnabled);

    self.nextButtonColor = nextButtonEnabled ? [UIColor primaryBlueColor] : [UIColor inactiveButtonColor];
}


@end
```

Log shows that `nextButtonEnabled` is changing correctly in `ViewModel`. But `View` doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an error. My `viewModel` was nil.

I am inheriting my controller from another one. And I initialized `ViewModel` in `ViewDidLoad`, which is called after `bindViewModel`. Because `bindViewModel` is called in `ViewDidLoad` of a parent controller.

Now I initialize `viewModel` in `initWithCoder`, not `ViewDidLoad`:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if ( self ) {
        self.viewModel = [[REPhoneViewModel alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}


/*- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.viewModel = [[REPhoneViewModel alloc] init];
}*/
```